# proj4js and GRS 1980

Tags: proj4js

I'm trying to convert GRS 1980 (ellipsoid) to WGS84 using Proj4js. 
The code that I'm currently using is:

```
proj4('GRS1980','WGS84'[184058,674431]);
```

The problem is that Proj4js does not accept GRS1980 (getting uncaught GRS1980).

How can I properly put GRS 1980 as an input for Proj4js?

Answer (score 2):

`proj4()` expects a projection definition, not just an ellipsoid.

From http://proj4js.org/ you might read that `WGS84` is the only named projection defined in proj4js. You have to use the listed EPSG codes or define the projection in full.

So your command might be:

```
var firstProjection = "+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +no_defs";
var secondProjection = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";
proj4(firstProjection,secondProjection,[2,5]);
```

Apart from that, your coordinates are not in the range of proper WGS84, that is +/- 180/90 degrees. From the comments, it seems you are looking for

```
var firstProjection = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=31.73439361111111 +lon_0=35.20451694444445 +k=1.0000067 +x_0=219529.584 +y_0=626907.39 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=-48,55,52,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs" 
var secondProjection = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs";
```

Note that proj4js does not have all EPSG code numbers stored internally, like Proj.4 and GDAL have.

Comment: Seems like the above code you provide outputs the same coordination as you input. I tried looking for its ESPG here: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/ but even after adding Proj4js.defs["EPSG:2039"] it's still not giving the same result as in http://twcc.fr/en/?sc=WGS84&dc=EPSG%253A2039&wgs84=34.84416961669922%252C32.1820053487696&z=13&mt=terrain#

Comment: As far as I know, for proj.4 they are synonyms.

Comment: @user30184 from `proj -le` I see that the `rf` value differs slightly.

Comment: Confirmed by Frank Warmermdam in this mail thread http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GRS80-vs-GRS80-towgs84-0-0-0-td3851056.html  rf=298.257223563 WGS 84 vs. rf=298.257222101 GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980). I suppose that difference is so small that conversion from WGS84 into GRS80 is usually unnecessary.